# C++ Implicit cast for operator==

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I'm having trouble understanding why one template instantiation works in my code and another does not.

I am using this class template I created:

```
template <typename T>
struct Allocated {
public:
    const T& get() const& {
        return *ptr.get();
    }
    T& get() & {
        return *ptr.get();
    }
    T&& get() && {
        return std::move(*ptr.get());
    }

    operator T& () & {
        return *ptr.get();
    }

    operator const T& () const & {
        return *ptr.get();
    }

    operator const T () && {
        return std::move(* ptr.get());
    }

    template <typename U>
    Allocated(const U& u) : ptr(std::make_unique<T>(u)) {}
    template <typename U>
    Allocated(U&& u) : ptr(std::make_unique<T>(std::move(u))) {}
    Allocated()  = delete;
    Allocated(const Allocated& other) : Allocated(other.get()) {};
    Allocated& operator=(const Allocated& other) {
        ptr = std::make_unique<T>(*other.ptr);
    }
    Allocated(Allocated&& other) : Allocated(other.get()) {};
    Allocated& operator=(Allocated&& other) {
        ptr = std::move(other.ptr);
        return *this;
    }
    ~Allocated() = default;
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;
};
```

and this code works

```
    Allocated<int> u = 7;
    bool k1 = u.get() == u.get();
    bool k2 = u == u; // this works fine and calls `operator T&`
```

while this does not

```
    Allocated<std::string> u = "test";
    bool k1 = u.get() == u.get();
    bool k2 = u == u; // error here
```

Question1: why is `operator T&` called for int and not for std::string?

Question 2: how can I fix it for any type? I do not want to define `operator==` in `Allocated` and it should work for other operators like `Allocated<int>.operator>(Allocated<int>)` for example.

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion; it's always explicit. The term you're looking for in your title is "implicit conversion".

Comment: This is a valid question. I'd just like to point out that relying on both operand being implitly converted in the same expression seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: *how can I fix it for any type?*  By implementing `operator==` in `Allocated`.  *I do not want to define `operator==` in `Allocated`*  Well, then you are in a pickle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with this code is that it relies on `operator ==` to provide context for implicit type conversion. It works for `int` because there is a built-in `bool operator ==(int, int)` candidate. When compiler checks this candidate function it knows types of arguments and is able to perform an implicit type conversion by invoking `Allocated::operator int const &`. However it does not work with `string` because corresponding operator for `string` is actually a `template` (because `std::string` is an alias for `std::basic_string` `template`) and therefore when compiler checks this candidate it does not know types of arguments and needs to deduce them first.

The following simplified examples illustrate the difference:

```
template <typename T>
struct Allocated
{
    operator T const & () const;
};
```

Type of argument of operator == is known to be `NotTemplate const &`, leading to successful implicit conversion.
[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/6eh9f1vYf)

```
struct NotTemplate{};

bool operator ==(NotTemplate const &, NotTemplate const &);

Allocated<NotTemplate> not_template{};
bool not_template_cmp{not_template == not_template}; // ok
```

Type of argument of `operator ==` is not known in advance, first `Dummy` must be deduced from `Allocated<Template<void>>`, which is impossible.
[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/77fdGoKhx)

```
template<typename Dummy>
struct Template{};

template<typename Dummy>
bool operator ==(Template<Dummy> const &, Template<Dummy> const &);

Allocated<Template<void>> _template{};
bool _template_cmp{_template == _template}; // error, no match...
```

Type of argument of an additional `operator ==` overload is known to be `Template<void>`, leading to successful implicit conversion.
[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/PG3YYorE5)

```
template<typename Dummy>
struct Template{};

template<typename Dummy>
bool operator ==(Template<Dummy> const &, Template<Dummy> const &);

bool operator ==(Template<void> const &, Template<void> const &);

Allocated<Template<void>> _template{};
bool _template_cmp{_template == _template}; // ok
```

One way to deal with this issue is to implement `operator ==` (or maybe even a spaceship operator in fresh C++ standard) overloads, including those accepting `T const &` is one of tne arguments, for `Allocated` class (and btw it should probably check that `ptr` is not null).

Comment: So weird how it works for types but not instances of templates, I thought it must have been  a special case only for built in types like int!

as for that comment about ptr is not null, the type is built to avoid that, i am replacing use of std::unique_ptr in my code with that in order to remove uses of pointers like an optional.

thanks